# Why can I not put the limit inside the limit definition of $e$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

We know $e:= \lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$

We also know $x^n$ is continuous. Why is there a contradiction in the following?

$e=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=(\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n}))^n=1$

Is it because $x^n$ isn't really a continuous function, because the $n$ is not fixed but rather something like infinity?

Comment: Because $n$ isn't a fixed number, so it's presence *outside* of the limit is meaningless

Comment: We say $1^\infty$ is an **indeterminete form**.  Look that up in your calculus textbook.

Comment: Note that once you put "the limit inside the limit definition" as shown, the exponent $n$ is no longer in the scope of taking a limit as $n\to\infty$.  As such, the meaning of  $n$ the exponent is no longer tied to the $n$ that is in the innermost parentheses.   Both need to be taken to the limit together to have the original meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't move a limit that depends on $n$ "inside" the function if the outside function depends on $n$. For example, it is clearly true that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n= \infty .$$

However, if you move the limit "inside," you get

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n= (\lim_{n \to \infty} 2)^n=2^n$$

which does not make much sense, since you do not know what $n$ is... $n$ was supposed to go to infinity. However, since you "got rid of" the limit, $n$ has no meaning anymore.

In other words, whenever you are calculating limits, $n$ should disappear at the same step as the words $\lim_{n \to \infty}$. If these two things don't go away at the same time, most likely it is a sign that you did something wrong.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Well explained. The limit operation and the variable bound to it go together.

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem is you can't write $(\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n))^n$, or anything else that uses $n$ outside the limit, because it's a dummy variable that exists only inside the limit. The role of $\infty$ is irrelevant; you also can't, for the same reason, jump from $\lim_{x\to 2}(x+x)=4$ to writing $(\lim_{x\to 2}x)+x$.

Answer (score 0):

Because the exponent is variable depending. In this case you get $1^{\infty}$ which is indeterminate, or means merely that this limit can be anything.